# Entity Framework 4.1 Codefirst: "Given multiplicity constraints" error when deleting one-to-many children

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, one-to-many

I have the following classes in **Entity Framework 4.1** (the classes have been pruned to keep the code readable)

```
public class MetaInformation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MetaInformationObject RelatedTo { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MetaInformationObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MetaInformation> MetaInformations { get; set; }
}

[Table("Hardwares")]
public class Hardware : MetaInformationObject
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}

public class Machine : Hardware
{
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Isis.Business.Base.MetaInformationObject>()
        .HasMany<Isis.Business.Base.MetaInformation>(mi => mi.MetaInformations).WithRequired(mi => mi.RelatedTo).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Isis.Business.Inventory.Inventory>()
            .HasMany<Isis.Business.Inventory.Machine>(i => i.Machines).WithRequired(m => m.Inventory).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

---

At one point, i'd like to update a machine information, so if it already exists in the database, i load it, attach it and then clear the previous metainformations to replace them with the new ones.

```
public void UpdateMachine(Inventory i, Machine m)
{
    DataContext.Dao.Db.Inventories.Attach(i);
    if (!i.Machines.Exists(InnerHardware => InnerHardware.SerialNumber == m.SerialNumber)) {
        i.Machines.Add(m);
    } else {
        var workingMachine = i.Machines.First(Machine => Machine.SerialNumber == m.SerialNumber);
        Dao.Db.Machines.Attach(workingMachine);
        if (workingMachine.MetaInformations != null && workingMachine.MetaInformations.Count > 0) {
            workingMachine.MetaInformations.Clear();
            //workingMachine.MetaInformations.ForEach(mi => { Dao.Db.MetaInformations.Attach(mi); Dao.Db.MetaInformations.Remove(mi); }); // tried this to, with variations
        }
        workingMachine.MetaInformations = m.MetaInformations;
    }
    DataContext.Dao.Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And then, the following DbUpdateException is thrown:

> A relationship from the 'MetaInformationObject_MetaInformations'
>   AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity
>   constraints, a corresponding
>   'MetaInformationObject_MetaInformations_Target' must also in the
>   'Deleted' state.

I tried following some questions here on SO to solve the problem, especially trying to read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883797/how-do-i-delete-a-child-entity-from-a-parent-collection-with-entity-framework-4) and [the link](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx) provided in the answer (that's the reason why there's a direct reference from `MetaInformation` to `MetaInformationObject`) but i can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cascade delete will not help you here. Cascade delete works only if you delete parent entity (`MetaInformationObject`). The problem here is that calling Clear on the collection of related objects doesn't delete them. It only deletes the relation (= it will set foreign key in `MetaInformation` to null) but it is not allowed by your mapping constraints (you defined relation as required). The ways to avoid this are either:

- Iterate through all related `MetaInformation`s and delete each of them
- Refactor you model to define [identifying relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922228/entity-framework-4-delete-object-from-entity-collection/4925040#4925040). After that `Clear` will not only break the relation but mark related entity as deleted as well.

Comment: I already tried to add `workingMachine.MetaInformations.ForEach(mi => Dao.Db.MetaInformations.Remove(mi));` just after the clear call, but i get the same error. I'm going to try and refactor the model follownig your second link. I'll keep you posted

Comment: You must delete them before Clear. After clear the collection is empty!

Comment: Gaaah, I feel like an idiot for not noticing it earlier. However, moving the removal before the clear doesn't solve the problem. Do you have an example of identifying relation declared in EF4 Codefirst?

Answer (score 0):

Echoing above comment, below code would solve your problem

DataContext.Dao.Db.MetaInformations.RemoveRange(workingMachine.MetaInformations);